# Excel VBA- Toggle row highlighting with each click of a macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that highlights a row if there is anything blank text in a specific column.  This macro is used to highlight areas where a user needs to direct attention.  I want to be able to unhighlight those rows after changes have been made, by clicking the same macro button.

How do I do this?

This is the current macro:

```
Sub Macro13() 
       With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    With ActiveSheet
       .Select
        ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
        .DisplayPageBreaks = False

        Firstrow = 2
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row

        For Lrow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1

             With .Cells(Lrow, "M")
                 If .Value = "" Then
                    .EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                End If
             End With


        Next Lrow
    End With

    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

End Sub
```

My idea was to, at the beginning of the macro, check to see if any row was highlighted red.  If so, run a new loop that iterates through all columns, removing the cell highlighting, and then after that loop is done, break out of the macro.  This is ugly and riddled with errors, though.

```
Sub Macro13() 'Checks for Incorrect Countries

   With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

With ActiveSheet
   .Select
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    .DisplayPageBreaks = False

    Firstrow = 2
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row

    FirstrowA = 2
    LastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row

    For Lrow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1

         With .Cells(Lrow, "M")
             If .EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
                   For LrowA = LastRowA To FirstrowA Step -1
                            .EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
                             Next LrowA
                    End
                Exit Sub
             End If


             If .Value = "" Then
                .EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
         End With
    Next Lrow
End With

ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you not do this with conditional formatting? i.e. Excel can apply formatting based on given conditions. Does that help?

Comment: I would second @shahkalpesh suggestion: this is a very good case to use conditional formatting to highlight blanks.  No need for a macro.

Comment: The macro is part of a suite that I am developing for my company.  As many people are unfamiliar with conditional formatting, I'd prefer to have it contained in a macro.

Comment: what's a "click of a macro" ?

Comment: when you click the button associated with the macro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick for you.  I've added a loop that looks for any formatting before it starts highlighting blanks.  If if finds something red, it clears the whole sheet of red formatting and raises a flag (Tracker = True).  When the flag is raised, the macro will not 
format blank cells' rows as red.  I tested it and it worked for me.

```
Sub Macro13()
   With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

With ActiveSheet
   .Select
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    .DisplayPageBreaks = False

    Firstrow = 2
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim Tracker As Boolean
    Tracker = False
    For Lrow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1
        If .Cells(Lrow, "M").EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            .Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
            Tracker = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Lrow

    If Tracker = False Then
        For Lrow = LastRow To Firstrow Step -1

            With .Cells(Lrow, "M")
                If .Value = "" Then
                    .EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                End If
            End With

        Next Lrow
    End If
End With

ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue before and conditional formating didn't work well for me.  I used something similar to this:

```
Sub CheckAndHighlight(area As Range, Optional ByVal searchValue As String = "")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim r As Range
For Each r In area
    r.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 0

    If r.Value = searchValue Then
    r.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You might add `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before the loop, `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` after the writing/formatting is done to speed up/avoid the flicker.

Comment: So, I believe that this only toggles the color off once the cell is no longer blank.  I want the macro to toggle the color irrespective of whether it is blank or not.  If red --> white; if white --> red.

Comment: @parseltongue I suggest you try to adapt the given code to your situation.